# Magento issue : no images, no theme, no CSS

Tags: magento, xampp

I'm tried to work on my Magento site in local environment : Xampp on windows 7. I used to do it all the time but this time I have a strange issue : My site is loaded with no images, no CSS and no theme at all !! Tried to find something on google but no luck. Could any one help me pls? attached are the screenshots of the two sides : local and online.
[Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBNEl.jpg)

[Online](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcNcj.jpg)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

- Remove everything, except .htaccess file from `pub/static` folder.
- Open up `app/etc/di.xml` and find the path:

  Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Symlink

and replace with:

```
Magento\Framework\App\View\Asset\MaterializationStrategy\Copy
```

**Note:** Remove entire files and folder under `pub/static` except `.htaccess` file.

Comment: I really appreciate you answer. Tried to follow the steps but can't find pub/static folder !! maybe it's the real issue. Do you have any other workaround? Thanks in advance.